# Передача значения из View в Model и последующий вызов метода - как?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, инспекция-кода

Следуя паттерну MVVM имеем View, ViewModel и некие классы для Model, в частности ExcelImporter для импорта и парсинга экселевского файла.

Во вьюхе есть поле ввода адреса файла. Биндится к соответствующему свойству в VM:

```
public string ExcelPath
{
    get
    {
        return excelPath;
    }

    set
    {
        excelPath = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ExcelPath"); //?
    }
}
```

Вопрос 1: если значение `ExcelPath` меняется *только из вьюхи* пользователем через диалоговое окно выбора файла, то во ViewModel в сеттере ему ведь не нужно делать `OnPropertyChanged("ExcelPath")`? И, следовательно, нужно в биндинге оставить `Mode=Default` (он же `OneWay`)?

Также в VM есть экземпляр класса `ExcelImporter`, который отвечает за импорт файла, со свойством, опять же, `ExcelPath`.

Вопрос 2: где будет корректным передавать значение из `VM.ExcelPath` в `ExcelImporter.ExcelPath`? В сеттере `VM.ExcelPath`? Или ещё была шальная мысль сделать событие `ExcelPathChanged`, на которое подписать саму же `VM`, и в обработчике устанавливать `ExcelImporter.ExcelPath = ExcelPath`. Или подписать на это событие `ExcelImporter`, но это по MVVM вроде как совсем неправильно.

```
public string ExcelPath
{
    get
    {
        return excelPath;
    }

    set
    {
        excelPath = value;
        ExcelImporter.ExcelPath = ExcelPath; //?
    }
}
```

Вопрос 2.1: а можно вообще вот так сделать свойство в VM?

```
public string ExcelPath
{
    get
    {
        return ExcelImporter.ExcelPath;
    }

    set
    {
        ExcelImporter.ExcelPath = value;
    }
}
```

Вопрос 3: если в сеттере, то что именно присваивать: `value`, `excelPath` или, как в вопросе 2, `ExcelPath`?

```
public string ExcelPath
{
    get
    {
        return excelPath;
    }

    set
    {
        excelPath = value;
        ExcelImporter.ExcelPath = value; //?
        ExcelImporter.ExcelPath = excelPath; //?
        ExcelImporter.ExcelPath = ExcelPath; //?
    }
}
```

Вопрос 4: чтобы `ExcelImporter` сразу же после получения `ExcelPath` выполнял метод `Import()` - т.е. чтобы с точки зрения пользователя всё автоматически происходило после выбора файла из обычного `OpenFileDialog`, без всяких лишних нажатий кнопки типа "Импортировать" - этот метод должен вызываться где?
В сеттере `VM.ExcelPath`, в сеттере `ExcelImporter.ExcelPath` или через событие в `ExcelImporter`, какой-нибудь `ExcelPathChanged`, на которое подписан... сам же `ExcelImporter` или `VM`, и уже там в обработчике вызывать `ExcelImporter.Import()`?
Больше ничего в голову не приходит, а такое активное использование сеттера для кучи дополнительных действий вызывает сомнение.

Вообще задача простая: получить из View адрес файла, передать его в `ExcelImporter` и вызвать метод `Import()`. Может, вообще все вопросы неправильные, и это делается как-то по-другому? И суть вопросов не в том как это сделать *вообще*, а как сделать *правильно*, религиозно верно, так сказать, а не мартышкиным методом "абы работало" :)

PS
Прошу прощения за некоторое нарушение правил SO, за несколько вопросов сразу, но как видите они взаимосвязаны, и создавать несколько отдельных тем показалось лишним.

**UPD1**

@andrey-k

> Мне сложно было представить такую ситуацию, что импорт происходит сразу после ввода имени файла, минуя нажатие кнопки

Ну поле, оно же TextBox, существует постольку-поскольку, чтобы была возможность скопипастить адрес файла, но в осноном конечно же выбор через винапишный OpenFileDialog. Хотя всё это сводится к одному - по сути что ввод ручками пользователя, что OpenFileDialog возвращает строкой путь к файлу. Разумеется, его нужно проверить. Но не вижу никакого смысла вынуждать пользователя тыкаться лишний раз ещё в какие-то кнопки после указания файла. Выбор документа и выуживание из него определённых данных - это первые 50% функционала.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По вопросу 1: View не должно знать, кто и как меняет свойства в VM. Завтра вы поменяете VM, и при этом вы не должны менять ещё и View. Пусть каждый из уровней заботится только о себе.

По поводу `OnPropertyChanged("ExcelPath"); //?`: лучше писать, конечно, так:

```
void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

и пользоваться просто `NotifyPropertyChanged()`:

```
string excelPath;
public string ExcelPath
{
    get { return excelPath; }
    set { if (excelPath != value) { excelPath = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }
}
```

По поводу того, когда обновлять модель — это решать вам и только вам. Может быть, обновлять модель сразу неправильно, а нужно подождать, пока пользователь скомандует «вот сейчас давайте». А может быть, нужно обновлять её как можно скорее. Вы как архитектор вашего приложения должны решать такие вопросы сами.

В любом случае, обновление модели — дело VM, а не наоборот.

По вопросу 2.1 — технически так делать можно, да (но не забудьте `NotifyPropertyChanged()`). Вопрос в том, правильно ли это для вашего случая. Например, если модель бежит не в главном потоке, то доступ к ней из UI-потока может быть неверным.

По вопросу 3 — не имеет ровно никакого значения. Все три значат одно и то же. (Я всё же не использовал бы `ExcelPath`, чтобы не идти лишний раз через getter, но это вопрос личных предпочтений.)

По поводу вопроса 4 — опять-таки это не диктуется паттерном MVVM. Всё определяется лично вами. Я бы делал так: при выставлении setter'а проверял значение на правильность, проверял, можно ли запускать импорт, и при этом условии запускал бы:

```
string excelPath;
public string ExcelPath
{
    get { return excelPath; }
    set
    {
        if (excelPath == value)
            return;
        excelPath = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
        OnPathChanged();
    }
}

async void OnPathChanged()
{
    if (!IsValidPath(excelPath))
    {
        SetInvalidFlag(); // so UI can pick it up
        return;
    }

    await BookNewImport();
}

ExcelImporter currentImporter, pendingImporter;
async Task BookNewImport()
{
    var importer = new ExcelImporter(ExcelPath);
    if (currentImporter != null)
    {
        pendingImporter = importer;
        await currentImporter.CancelAsync();
        if (pendingImporter != importer) // new import booked
            return;                      // so not run ours
    }
    currentImporter = importer;
    await currentImporter.ImportAsync();
    if (currentImporter == importer)
        currentImporter = null;
    // else there's other importer running
}
```

Это лучше тем, что модель дёргается только после всех проверок. Плюс, поскольку импорт — процесс по сути длительный, я бы сделал к нему async-интерфейс, и не блокировал вызывающий поток (как это сделано в сниппете выше).

Comment: "По поводу того, когда обновлять модель — это решать вам и только вам" - так сразу же, я уже решил :) Вопрос в том, как это сделать архитектурно красиво. Ну я так понял, что вызывать метод OnPathChanged в сеттере это нормально. Были сомнения отчего-то.  "По вопросу 2.1 — технически так делать можно, да (но не забудьте NotifyPropertyChanged())." - а зачем NotifyPropertyChanged, если значение изменено из View? И за NotifyPropertyChanged через CallerMemberName спасибо, удобненько!)

Comment: @eexaxa: По поводу _а зачем NotifyPropertyChanged, если значение изменено из View_: Ну, это сейчас у вас только один View отображает этот объект. А завтра вы нужно будет отображать тот же объект одновременно во втором View. Или как-то ещё поменяется использование. Если свойство меняется откуда бы то ни было, нужно поддерживать INPC. Экономить на этом из соображений «ну у меня же сейчас это не нужно» — прямой путь к необъяснимым багам в будущем. Делайте сразу правильно. Объект не должен знать, как именно его будут использовать.

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю как идеально, но могу сказать, как бы я сделал и почему.

Я бы сделал так:

```
    private string _ExcelPath;
    public string ExcelPath
    {
        get
        {
            return _ExcelPath;
        }
        set
        {
            _ExcelPath = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ExcelPath");
        }
    }
```

Делал свой пример не для диалога, а для поля, потому что прочитал

> Во вьюхе есть поле ввода адреса файла

---

Сначала расскажу для случая с **полем**. То есть, когда пользователь вводит имя файла вручную. В своем примере предусмотрел развитие кода по следующем направлениям:

- Мне сложно было представить такую ситуацию, что импорт происходит сразу после ввода имени файла, минуя нажатие кнопки. Поэтому я на скорую руку сделал свою имплементацию `ICommand`. Во вью моделе определил эту команду, как свойство. Таким образом, вызов импортера не может произойти просто после ввода каких-то символов в поле, но происходит по вызову метода `Execute()` команды. При выполнении этого метода и считывается свойство `ExcelPath`.
- Сервис импорта не вызывается в сеттере в том числе и потому, что теоретически имя файла нужно бы сначала проверить, провести валидацию, а потом уже что-то с ним делать.
- Если подумать о пользовательском интерфейсе, то хорошо бы выводить адекватные сообщения об ошибках. В *XAML*, для поля ввода файла установлено `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`. После ввода каждого нового символа происходит обновления свойства вью модели, а так же изменяется состояние кнопки и индикатора. Если формат имени файла неверный, то кнопка серая и горит красный восклицательный знак. Красный восклицательный знак помимо серой кнопки введен для того случая, когда полей много, а кнопка одна, например, *ОК*. Тогда красный восклицательный знак показывает, какое именно поле косячное. Чтобы кнопка становилась серой, надо в сеттер добавить `ImportExcelFileCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()`.
- Вдруг когда-нибудь станет нужным сброс этого поля изнутри вью-модели, поэтому в сеттере есть `OnPropertyChanged("ExcelPath")` и `Mode=TwoWay`.
- Теоретически, может быть и такая ошибка, которая не может быть обнаружена до нажатия кнопки. Напимер, существует ли файл. И так же нужно вывести адекватное сообщение.
- Если следивать принцмпам *SOLID*, то хорошо бы инъектировать сервис импорта в конструктор вью модели. И интуитивно мне кажется, что имя файла должно быть параметром функции: `Import(fileName)`

Код:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private class ExcelImporter : IExcelImporter
    {
        public void Import(string excelFilePath)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(excelFilePath);
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = new ViewModel(new ExcelImporter());
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly IExcelImporter _ExcelImporter;
    public MyQuickCommand ImportExcelFileCommand { get; private set; } //implements ICommand

    private string _ExcelPath;
    public string ExcelPath
    {
        get
        {
            return _ExcelPath;
        }
        set
        {
            _ExcelPath = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ExcelPath");
            ImportExcelFileCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _ExcelPathFormatIsValid;
    public bool ExcelPathFormatIsValid  //if you want to indicate when the file format is incorrect
    {
        get
        {
            return _ExcelPathFormatIsValid;
        }
        set
        {
            _ExcelPathFormatIsValid = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ExcelPathFormatIsValid");
        }
    }

    public ViewModel(IExcelImporter excelImporter)
    {
        if (excelImporter == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("excelImporter");

        _ExcelImporter = excelImporter;
        ImportExcelFileCommand = new MyQuickCommand(Import, IsExcelPathFormatValid);
    }

    private void Import()
    {
        if (!ExcelFileExists())
        {
            //indicate error
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                _ExcelImporter.Import(_ExcelPath);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }

    private bool IsExcelPathFormatValid()
    {
        bool validationResult;

        throw new NotImplementedException("ExcelPathIsValid");

        ExcelPathFormatIsValid = validationResult;
        return validationResult;
    }

    private bool ExcelFileExists()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("FileExists");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

`ICommand`:

```
public class MyQuickCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _Execute;
    private readonly Func<bool> _CanExecute;

    public MyQuickCommand(Action executeAction)
        : this(executeAction, () => true)
    {

    }

    public MyQuickCommand(Action executeAction, Func<bool> canExecuteFunc)
    {
        if (executeAction == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("executeAction");

        if (canExecuteFunc == null)
            canExecuteFunc = () => true;

        _Execute = executeAction;
        _CanExecute = canExecuteFunc;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = delegate { };

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (parameter != null)
            throw new NotSupportedException("CanExecute MyCommand with parameter is not supported");

        return _CanExecute();
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (parameter != null)
            throw new NotSupportedException("Execute MyCommand with parameter is not supported");

        _Execute();
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

public interface IExcelImporter
{
    void Import(string excelFilePath);
}
```

*XAML*:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="!" Foreground="DarkRed" Visibility="{Binding Path=ExcelPathFormatIsValid, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ExcelPath, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <Button Content="Import" Command="{Binding ImportExcelFileCommand}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

---

Для случая с **диалогом**, `ICommand` остается. Диалог вызывается изнутри метода `Execute()`. Единственное, тогда свойство `ExcelPath` вообще не нужно, а приватные методы проверки будут принимать имя файла как параметр.

*Update:* имел ввиду, что и поле `TextBox` тоже не нужно для копирования, а чтобы path получался напрямую из вью модели и из вью модели вызывался диалог через команду.

---

Если отвечать конкретно на вопросы, то, с моей точки зрения:

- 1 - `Mode=TwoWay`. *Update*: это на случай если в будущем надо будет сбросить поле изнутри
- 2 - `ICommand`, как свойство вью-модели
- 2.1 - мне не нравится такая привязка напрямую. Во первых, может понадобиться валидация. Во вторых, мне кажется не очень красиво спроектирован сервис. Думаю, что должен быть метод `importServiceInstance.Import(fileName)`.
- 3 - если имя файла устанавливается именно так, то я бы сделал `ExcelImporter.ExcelPath = excelPath`, потому что так нагляднее, чем `=value`, и не вызывает цепочек вызовов, как если `=ExcelPath`.
- 4 - `ICommand`. Хотя бы один раз нажать кнопку придется, чтобы открыть диалог. А оттуда из метода `Execute()` открывать диалог и потом вызывать импорт.

---

P.S. Если надоедает каждый раз писать `OnPropertyChanged("name")`, то рекоммендую посмотреть [Fody](https://github.com/Fody) **PropertyChanged**

Comment: Спасибо за большой и развёрнутый ответ, но, наверное, я некорректно задал вопрос =(

>Мне сложно было представить такую ситуацию, что импорт происходит сразу после ввода имени файла, минуя нажатие кнопки

Об этом добавил UPD1 в вопросе.

А вот выделение метода Import во вьюмодели - интересная мысль, спасибо. Такое не приходило в голову.

PS
Я совсем начинающий, поэтому стараюсь избегать фреймворков, чтобы было поменьше закулисной магии.

Comment: @eexaxa, для случая диалога, я написал один абзац в своем ответе. Там я сказал, что если *диалог*, то _TextBox_ и _поле_ во вью-модели вообще не нужны. Зачем куда-то промежуточно копировать? Можно из вью модели вызвать диалог и там обработать path. Кажется, для открытия диалога кнопка все равно нужна. Для этого мне кажется хорошим тоном ввести `ICommand` и в методе `Execute()` производить дейтсвия. Странно, что VladD в ничего не написал про `ICommand`. Даже если кнопка вообще не нужна и диалог вызывается, например, автоматически при открытии окна, то я бы все равно ввел `ICommand` на всякий.

Comment: Смотрите, во вьюхе есть текстбокс (его я и называю "поле ввода", а не "поле" == field). Юзеру видно адрес файла, он может его оттуда скопировать или его туда вставить. Или перетащить файл на этот текстбокс из проводника (пока в планах). Удобненько же!
Рядом кнопка "Обзор". - открывает диалог выбора файла. В общем-то, это сделано через команду, да. Но - эта кнопка не обязательно будет нажата. Единственное, что я вижу общего между этими ситуациями - в текстбоксе будет адрес. Откуда он там возьмётся - дело десятое. Мб вообще подтянется из прошлой сессии (в планах).

Comment: @eexaxa, а что если такая ситуация: пользователь начал по памяти вводить имя файла, потом понял, что он не вспомнит, решил скопировать из другого места, но то, что он уже успел ввести в поле передалось во вью-модель => начинаются предъимпортные проверки и появляется раздражающее сообщение об ошибке. Мне кажется, что кнопка нужна. В том числе и потому, что если посмотреть "Browse button"  в google images, то показываются в основном либо поле и 2 кнопки или 1 кнопка без поля. В начале списка картинок есть исключение, но это не похоже на законченную программу. Простите если чего не так понимаю.

Comment: А сообщение должно быть не раздражающим :) "Browse button" в google images - там 99% выбор файла для загрузки в сеть. Если посмотреть тот же Browse для вложений в Google Mail, то можно заметить, что файл начинает грузиться сразу после выбора. Мне как раз кажется, что лишние кнопки - от ленности программистов, а не пожелание UX - чертовски удобно дёргать методы просто по нажатию кнопки, типа, юзеру виднее, когда он хочет грузить файл. Но на самом деле сценарий в 99% одинаковый, поэтому лучше упростить его, за счёт усложнения оставшегося 1% (окей, не тот файл выбран - придётся нажать крестик).

Comment: @eexaxa, простите не до конца понимаю. В gmail одна кнопка, но поле где отображается имя файла не редактируется. Если оно не редактируется, то понятно. Если требуется нажатие Enter, то тоже понятно. Ну да ладно, значит как Вы считаете, то и правильнее. Я не спец и вашего контекста не знаю. В windows файл тоже редактируется примерно так, пользователь вводит новое имя файла, затем когда щелкает в сторону, то происходит операция переименования.